# Error: [$rootScope:infdig] on array push operation

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I have an array that is used as the data for a table in my html.

On click of a button am adding (pushing) a new value to this array, which inturn will add a new row in the table

To add the new value to the array am using $scope.on and $scope.$broadcast implementations of Angularjs

Now the problem is the new value is getting adding to the array and the same is getting updated in the table (in UI) but the "Error: [$rootScope:infdig]" is getting throwed. Am not sure what is wrong with my code.

html:

```
<tr ng-repeat="employee in employeelist">
<td >{{employee.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.employeelist = [];
$scope.$on("employee", function (event, args) {
   $scope.addEmployee(args);
});
```

and here is the addEmployee() method:

```
 $scope.addEmployee = function(newemp) {
   $scope.employeelist.push(newemp);
```

};

on click of a button i will broadcast with the new value (new employee) as below (please note that this a dynamic value. I have hardcoded here only for demonstration):

```
 $scope.add = function () {
    var emp = {name:'test'};
    $rootScope.$broadcast("employee", emp);
}
```

will be glad if anybody helps in getting this error resolved.

UPDATE:

I figured out the issue. The issue is with the "stSafeSrc" attribute that is being set on the table (am using smart table, which i missed to mention in my post). The idea is to use a seperate collection for both the base (st-table) and safe collections (stSafeSrc) or it will end up with an infinite loop. I missed this part which i found [here](http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/?utm_source=angular-js.in&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=content-curation)

Comment: Are you inject $rootscope in your controller??

Comment: yes, $rootscope is injected in the controller

Comment: Any error in console you have ?

Comment: yes..this is the error - "Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.22/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%22fn%3…2%3A%5C%221%5C%22%2C%5C%22description%5C%22%3A%5C%221%5C%22%7D%5D%22%5D%5D"

Comment: any reason you're using events for this? I mean, most use cases I've seen have an ng-click on the button that calls an add function on the controller, or it calls an add function on a service (in case the button is in another controller than the list)

Comment: yes. I have a modal dialog (with its own controller) to accept the details of an employee. When the user clicks on "add" button in the modal dialog, am broadcasting this event to the parent controller with the entered data to update the data in the table. And another thing i have observed is that, the same error is thrown when updating or deleting an object from this array